# insert values from a column in Table A to Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

Table "content" has a primary key as ID

```
ID    name     languages_ID
============================
33   lesson1     16
34   lesson2     17
```

Table "content_progress" has a primary key as ID and foreign key as content_ID

```
ID   content_ID 
================
1      33     
2      33           
3      33         
4      34
```

I added a column in table content_progress as languages_ID where its values should be filled from languages_ID column in content table where content.ID = content_progress.content_ID

I have tried different SQL queries without desired result.

```
INSERT INTO content_progress (languages_ID) 
SELECT
    languages_ID
FROM
    content
WHERE
    content.id = content_progress.content_ID;
```

```
ID   content_ID   languages_ID
============================
1      33            16
2      33            16
3      33            16
4      34            17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` creates new rows in a table. Since you already have rows and just want to update them, you'll need to use an `update` statement, or more specifically, an update-join statement:

```
UPDATE content_progress cp
JOIN   content c ON c.id = cp.content_id
SET    cp.languages_id = c.languages_id
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked like a charm. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes as per the restriction of stackoverflow.